# Set template for route from controller

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to set a template dynamically for a route from within controller.

I have this working fine:

```
when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'front/templates/user/profile.html',
    controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
}).
```

I wish to load template according to logged user. For example, if a doctor logs in, I need to load /doctor/profile.html instead of /user/profile.html

I tried to inject SessionServ into config but it failed, whereas same SessionServ is injecting into controllers:

```
angular.module('main').config(
  ['$httpProvider', '$routeProvider', 'SessionServ', 
  function($httpProvider, $routeProvider, SessionServ) {
```

Is there a way that from within ProfileCtrl, I can do something like this:

```
if(isUser){
   $scope.setTemplate('front/templates/user/profile.html');
}
else if(isDoctor){
   $scope.setTemplate('front/templates/doctor/profile.html');
}
```

I also tried this but didn't work:

```
$scope.current.templateUrl = 'front/templates/doctor/profile.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

I made following changes:

1. Created file:  **front/templates/profile.html** with following line:

   `<div ng-include="template"></div>`
2. Created following files:

   front/templates/user/profile.html

   front/templates/doctor/profile.html
3. In my config, added following lines:

   `when('/profile', {
       templateUrl: 'front/templates/profile.html',
       controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
   })`
4. In my ProfileCtrl, added following code:

   `if(isUser){
       $scope.template = 'front/templates/user/profile.html';
   }
   else if(isDoctor){
       $scope.template = 'front/templates/doctor/profile.html';
   }`